# Why the duplication in .NET Core math methods?

Tags: c#, .net

In .NET Core (all versions, far as I can tell), the `System.MathF` class has float versions of all the System.Math methods.

Also, in .NET 7, the numeric types have static math methods added, such as `Sin`.

In the following snippet, y and z both receive a `float` result:

```
float f = 1.2f;
var y = MathF.Sin(f);
var z = float.Sin(f);
```

My question is: why the duplication? Are there some benefits to the newer math methods on the float type that I'm not seeing, that aren't already there via `System.MathF`?

Comment: Just a better naming convention?

Comment: If you reflect into the extension method `Sin` you see this: `return MathF.Sin(x);`

Comment: It might have something to do with the introduction of the `INumber<T>` interface: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/math.  My guess is that that work led to a lot of refactoring

Comment: .NET notoriously did not allow implementing anything like a `Complex<T>` generic type.  That was addressed in .NET7, System.Single, Single.Double etc now implement [`ITrigonometricFunctions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.itrigonometricfunctions-1?view=net-7.0).  No need to use it here.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Really? float.Sin looks that much better than MathF.Sin ?

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: `MathF.Sin` at least gives you a clue about the data type, but `Math.Sin` does not.  Meanwhile `float.Sin` vs `double.Sin` is perfectly clear about the type.

Comment: Voting to open.  The question is borderline _opinion based_.  @Guru's excellent answer is not opinion based at all.  This deserves to be in the SO library of programming information.

Comment: I don't see why it was deemed "opinion based" - the answer from Guru Stron was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Good point - thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`MathF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.mathf?view=net-7.0) and its [`MathF.Sin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.mathf.sin?view=net-7.0#system-mathf-sin(system-single)) method were introduced in .NET Core 2.0:

> Applies to:

| Product | Versions |
| --- | --- |
| .NET | Core 2.0, Core 2.1, Core 2.2, Core 3.0, Core 3.1, 5, 6, 7, 8 |
| .NET Standard | 2.1 |

while `Single.Sin` (or [`float.Sin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.sin?view=net-7.0#system-single-sin(system-single))) was introduced in .NET 7:

> Applies to:

| Product | Versions |
| --- | --- |
| .NET | 7, 8 |

with [generic math](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/math) introduction and is implementation of [static abstract interface method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/static-abstracts-in-interfaces) [`ITrigonometricFunctions<TSelf>.Sin(TSelf)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.itrigonometricfunctions-1.sin?view=net-7.0#system-numerics-itrigonometricfunctions-1-sin(-0)). And internally (in current implementation) it is using `MathF.Sin` - [source.dot.net](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Single.cs,1791). And obviously for compatibility reasons `MathF.Sin` could not be removed (even if the implementation would be moved to `Single.Sin`)

> Are there some benefits to the newer math methods on the float type that I'm not seeing, that aren't already there via System.MathF?

Yes - they can be used in generic methods (with appropriate generic constraints), which is the reason for the generic math feature introduction:

```
public T MyFunc<T>(T value) where T : ITrigonometricFunctions<T>
{
    var res = T.Sin(value);
    return res;
}
```

And usage:

```
float f = 1;
MyFunc(f);
```